# Change TFS license type from MSDN to commercial

Tags: license, msdn, team-foundation-server

So I *accidentally* installed my MSDN license on a server and I'd like to change it to a commercial license.  Following [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668758.aspx), I do not see a "license expires" field or an "update license" option.  Is it possible to change the license without a reinstall?

Comment: The article you linked to only talks about moving from a trial to a registered version.  What you want to do requires you to reinstall TFS.